# How to enable PIP on an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, pip

Has anyone used the preview portal in Azure to configure a PIP for a VM?

When I go into the IP Addresses tab the "enable" button is grayed out.

The is for an "instance public IP". Is it just because the Preview Portal isn't always 100% just yet? I could do it in Powershell……but… ;)

Thanks!

Robert

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a [lack of basic research.](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft, it's not yet supported on the Portal (they don't say old or new one, but I would assume both)

> 3. Is the Instance level Public IP Address shown in the portal?
>
> No, at this point it is not supported through the portal. It is
>   exclusively available only through powershell cmd let and REST API

.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/22/instance-level-public-ip-address/

Comment: It's available in the preview portal. Navigate Vm >> Settings >> Ip address >> Enable Instance IP